# i want to add captcha with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, captcha

well i have a form in which email and captcha validation was there but now i want to do some thing like if captcha is incorrect or left empty than my form must not reload the page i.e all those field which are already been filled out must not get blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either

- A) Submit the form as you are doing right now, and fill the fields with the existing field data
- B) Use a CAPTCHA library that supports AJAX submission, e.g. reCAPTCHA http://wiki.recaptcha.net/index.php/Overview#AJAX_API

I believe that (A) is a lot better because it allows you to deal seamlessly with all other kinds of validation. But depending on what you already have (B) might be trivial to implement. So YMMV.